# Add or write to subelement of elements of list

Tags: r

From a list, I can **read** every second subelement of each element by `sapply(list, "[[", 2)`. I know how to write to or append a subelement to an element in a list.

Question:

How can I **write** (without a `for` loop, neither visible nor hidden beyond another function) to selected subelements in *each* element, or append an additional subelement to *each* element of a list? I am looking for a generic solution, independent from number of existing elements and subelements.

Eample:

let

```
   list.main <- list(
    list1 = list(a="a", b="b", c="c"), 
    list2 = list(e1="1", e2="2"), 
    list3 = list(aLpha="alpha", beta="beta"))
```

How to a add a further (secon or third, respectively) element `new="new"` to `list1`, `list2` and `list3` alltogether?

Lean and/or Base R solution preferred, but open to any solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, if you're happy to append the new elements at the end of each sublist, you can just do this...

```
lapply(list.main, function(x) c(x, new = "new"))

$list1
$list1$a
[1] "a"

$list1$b
[1] "b"

$list1$c
[1] "c"

$list1$new
[1] "new"


$list2
$list2$e1
[1] "1"

$list2$e2
[1] "2"

$list2$new
[1] "new"


$list3
$list3$aLpha
[1] "alpha"

$list3$beta
[1] "beta"

$list3$new
[1] "new"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `c`oncatenate the `list` element.

```
> lapply(list.main, c, list(NEW='NEW')) |> str()
List of 3
 $ list1:List of 4
  ..$ a  : chr "a"
  ..$ b  : chr "b"
  ..$ c  : chr "c"
  ..$ NEW: chr "NEW"
 $ list2:List of 3
  ..$ e1 : chr "1"
  ..$ e2 : chr "2"
  ..$ NEW: chr "NEW"
 $ list3:List of 3
  ..$ aLpha: chr "alpha"
  ..$ beta : chr "beta"
  ..$ NEW  : chr "NEW"
```

Or use `append`,

```
> lapply(list.main, append, list(NEW='NEW')) |> str()
List of 3
 $ list1:List of 4
  ..$ a  : chr "a"
  ..$ b  : chr "b"
  ..$ c  : chr "c"
  ..$ NEW: chr "NEW"
 $ list2:List of 3
  ..$ e1 : chr "1"
  ..$ e2 : chr "2"
  ..$ NEW: chr "NEW"
 $ list3:List of 3
  ..$ aLpha: chr "alpha"
  ..$ beta : chr "beta"
  ..$ NEW  : chr "NEW"
```

which enables you to specify e.g. after `1` element.

```
> lapply(list.main, append, list(NEW='NEW'), 1) |> str()
List of 3
 $ list1:List of 4
  ..$ a  : chr "a"
  ..$ NEW: chr "NEW"
  ..$ b  : chr "b"
  ..$ c  : chr "c"
 $ list2:List of 3
  ..$ e1 : chr "1"
  ..$ NEW: chr "NEW"
  ..$ e2 : chr "2"
 $ list3:List of 3
  ..$ aLpha: chr "alpha"
  ..$ NEW  : chr "NEW"
  ..$ beta : chr "beta"
```

Note, that missing elements are not filled.

```
> lapply(list.main, append, list(NEW='NEW'), 999) |> str()
List of 3
 $ list1:List of 4
  ..$ a  : chr "a"
  ..$ b  : chr "b"
  ..$ c  : chr "c"
  ..$ NEW: chr "NEW"
 $ list2:List of 3
  ..$ e1 : chr "1"
  ..$ e2 : chr "2"
  ..$ NEW: chr "NEW"
 $ list3:List of 3
  ..$ aLpha: chr "alpha"
  ..$ beta : chr "beta"
  ..$ NEW  : chr "NEW"
```